# How to select a name of a new list from existing string?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and I'm not able to solve this. In a loop, I have a list with some numbers and a string with the desired name of the list. I want to create a new list identical to the existing list a named it according to the name from the string.

`values = [1,2,3]
name='Ehu'`

What I need is a new list named 'Ehu' containing the same items as the list values, but I don't know how to select a name of the new list from existing string.

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a dictionary: `d = {name: values}`

Comment: `setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, values)`.

Comment: See [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [_Keep data out of your variable names_](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using `globals`:

```
>>> g = globals()
>>> name = 'Ehu'
>>> g['{}'.format(name)] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> Ehu 
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* do what you ask:

```
>>> globals()['Ehu'] = [1,2,3]
>>> Ehu
[1, 2, 3]
```

or for local variables:

```
>>> def f():
...   f.__dict__['Ehu'] = [1,2,3]
...   print(Ehu)
...
>>> f()
[1, 2, 3]
```

That is a bad practice.  A better solution as @Moses commented:

```
>>> list_names = {}
>>> list_names['Ehu'] = [1,2,3]
>>> print(list_names['Ehu'])
[1, 2, 3]
```